# how to apply alter table to multiple databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

how to apply "alter table" to multiple databases? e.g.

there are 10 databases all of which have table "Foo".

```
alter table Foo add name varchar2(30)
```

Any tools?

Comment: SQLite, Oracle, and MysQL are different database products with different implementations of SQL. I removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you use. Also, asking us to recommend a tool is explicitly off topic here on SO.

Comment: Run the code 10 times, once for each database.

Comment: @GordonLinoff that is what I want to avoid.

Comment: First of all, tell us what version of SQL you are using.  Then we might be able to help.

Comment: The data inside all of the `Foo` tables are the same?

Comment: it seems you can find the solution here, using dynamic SQL https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49993/alter-table-for-multiple-databases-same-table-name